# Disable change owner on specific record through UI but not through Apex

Tags: apex, ui

I'm looking for a way to disable a record's change owner for a specific profile through UI (for example it should disappear the change owner button on the related list view), but keeping it enabled through Apex code.

Comment: remove fls for owner field?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal  i've allready tryied with fls and validations, but eventually i've used a trigger and a custom field as a flag to disable owner change for that profile. Do you have any other idea which does not uses triggers and custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions, first, as @Pranay said, you can modifiy fls on owner fields.
Second, you can add a custom validation rule to avoid people to switch owner on specifics conditions ?